# Difference between HTMLTableSectionElement and HTMLTableElement

Tags: html, dom

Can somebody explain difference between this two elements. Apparently second one is parent of the first. But they both have insertRow and deleteRow methods.

Answer (score 2):

An [HTMLTableElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-64060425) represents a [`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

An [HTMLTableSectionElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-67417573) can represent a [`thead`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element), [`tfoot`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element) or a [`tbody`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element). These elements represent sections (each containing table row elements) within a table.

Comment: I'm still confused. You said "can represent".

Comment: @user2982390 — Yes? It can't be all three at the same time.